# Strange bug when running multiple instances of a PlayN game

Tags: java, multiplayer, playn, multiplatform

I'm currently developing a multiplayer game and it's common for me to launch a server plus 4 instances of my playn game.
When more than one instance is opened at the same time strange bugs begins to happen in all animations and layers of all instances. (blinking, wrong movements, things jump across the screen)
It seems like all instances are sharing a common state (openGL maybe?) and they are influenting each other.
I'm on Windows and I my co-worker that's using linux (ubuntu) dosent have the same problem.
Any tip? is this a bug? or a known limitation of windows implementation
thanks in advance

Comment: seems like resource sharing problem server(shared) objects are manipulated by multiple instances (clients) simultaneously. Read multi-threading and apply synchronisation.

Comment: Just to note: each instance runs in a separate process and JVM. (so I dont think it's PlayN data thats being shared but something about OpenGL)

Answer (score 1):

It is a Windows-only bug as far as I know of. On Mac, Linux and any other Unix processor, it runs perfectly. Also, you should try updating your JVM, it may work better.

Comment: You may want to provide a link to the bug, if it's a known bug.